# Illustrator Search Fonts and Select Font Family to Preserve Font Styles in Textbox

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

How do I search for a font and select it without changing all my text to one font style?

Selecting a font family without searching preserves the different font styles in a textbox by setting the closest matching style. This is the desired behavior.

[image: screenshot of a font family being selected without searching which preserves the font styles in the area text element]

Searching for a font displays a list of individual font styles and selecting one changes all of the text in the textbox to the selected style. I want to search for a type family and select it without overwriting the font styles I've set in my type object.

[image: screenshot of the font family being searched which changes all of the font styles in the text element to the selected style]

Perhaps there's a setting to show search results grouped by font family or a keyboard shortcut to preserve font styles while selecting a search result? Any tips or workarounds appreciated.

Comment: What about using Find/Replace Font in the Type menu?

Comment: "Find/Replace Font" replaces each font style individually. There's no option to replace an entire font family at once and I don't think you can limit Find/Replace to a single text box.

To clarify, selecting a font family from the character menu does a pretty good job preserving the font styles as you can see in my first screenshot, I'm trying to find a way to do that after searching for a font.

Comment: Contact adobe its a clear design oversight. But yeah activate the fonts then cancel search and assign the family.